# changing the order of Integration weirdly

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

So far what I understood is if your limits are some constant, you can find the volume under a function f(x,y) is $\begin{equation}
\int_{c}^{d} \int_{a}^{b}f(x,y) \,dx\,dy
\end{equation}$

and it is equal to $\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{b} \int_{c}^{d}f(x,y) \,dy\,dx
\end{equation}$

And if you have a variable limit its not always equal. But I came across a problem which looks like this:

$\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{x+2}f(x,y) \,dx\,dy
\end{equation}$

And here I am completely lost. I thought the question doesn't make any sense. As you can see the x limit is from x to x+2. why the x limit is not in y? How can I even draw the limit of x and x+2 in x-axis?

But in textbook they simply solved it by changing the order of Integration.

$\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{x+2}f(x,y) \,dx\,dy
\end{equation}$ = $\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{x+2}f(x,y) \,dy\,dx
\end{equation}$

And now the question looks normal. But can we just change the dx and dy anytime we want? I am completely lost here. Please help me!

Here is the actual question and the answer in a handwritten note that my teacher sent me.

[image: A handwriiten solution to a given problem]

Comment: You are correct... Once you put integration limits you must consider the corresponding order of integration. The first form is just wrong... i'd be careful with that "book". Or maybe you did not transcribe it accurately?

Comment: @PierreCarre I am wondering what actually the limit x ranges x to x+2 mean? How can I possibly even draw the limit of x and x+2 in x axis?

Comment: There is for sure some typo or misunderstand.

Comment: @PierreCarre I added a picture in the edit.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are expected to start by placing the differentials correctly and only then proceed with computing the integral. However this is a bad practice. If you only mention the integration set, for instance $\iint_D f(x,y) dx dy$, it is irrelevant in which order you place the differentials, but once you write the integration limits the differentials must be placed in the correct order.

Comment: @PierreCarre Yes, your explanation will actually make sense. But why would they ask such stupid questions like these? Is changing the order of differentiation a kind of jumbled words that we have to arrange it in a proper way. I hate these type of text books. Anyhow you actually saved me from lot of googling. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also be completely lost. The inner integral of $\int_x^{x+2} f(x, y) dx$ makes little sense. However, the integral $\int_x^{x+2}f(x, y) dy$ is sensible. I suspect it was a typo and they from the start meant
$$
\int_0^1\left(\int_x^{x+2}f(x, y)dy\right)dx
$$
Assuming $f$ is nicely behaved, and we really want to, we can swap the order of integration and get that the above integral is equal to
$$
\int_0^3\left(\int_{\max(0, y-2)}^{\min(y, 1)}f(x, y)dx\right)dy
$$
In general you can't just interchange $dx$ and $dy$ in a nested integral like that without changing the limits, and you certainly cannot do that in the two examples you've shown.

Comment: I added a picture in my question. I highly doubt it is a typo

Comment: @VigneshWar I saw the picture, and while it looks less like a typo than I thought it would, that doesn't change my response.